# Laço "while" terminando antes do esperado

Tags: c, while

A questão diz o seguinte:

> Escreva um programa que leia o lado de um quadrado e então imprima o quadrado
> com asteriscos. Seu programa deve funcionar com quadrados de todos os
> tamanhos entre 1 e 20. Por exemplo, se seu programa lesse um tamanho 4, deveria
> imprimir
>
> ```
> ****
> ****
> ****
> ****
> ```

Até essa parte do livro que estou lendo não se falou em `for` ou `do ... while`, apenas `while`. Então eu fiz esse código. Estou começando agora mas acho que deveria ter funcionado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int contador=1, linha=1, valor=0;
    printf("entre com o valor:\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    
    
    while (contador<=valor && linha<=valor) {
        printf("*");
        contador++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    contador = 1;
    linha++;
    return 0;
}
```

Não entendo, se eu coloquei no final do comando `while` que contador deveria voltar a ser `1`, o loop não deveria recomeçar?

Se puderem me dizer o que eu devo estudar pra consertar esse código, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há dois problema de lógica no seu código:

1. O  `while` executa em loop apenas os comandos dentro das chaves, assim, as linhas onde você atualiza os valores das variáveis `contador` e `linha` não estão sendo executadas;
2. Ao utilizar a condição `contador <= valor && linha <= valor`, no momento em que alguma das condições for falsa, sairá do `while`, então só vai imprimir uma linha com asteriscos.

Uma solução é utilizar dois loops `while` aninhados:

```
while (linha <= valor){ // Percorre as linhas
    while (contador <= valor) { // Percorre as colunas
        printf("*");
        contador++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    contador = 1;
    linha++;
}
```

Comment: obg por dizer onde eu errei. depois de ver o problema pareceu muito óbvio kkk. obg

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, você não está colocando `contador=1` dentro do `while`, mas sim dentro da `main`. Uma forma simples de fazer o que você deseja é utilizar 2 loops aninhados, dessa forma:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i=1, j=1, valor=0;
    printf("entre com o valor:\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &valor);

    while(i <= valor) {
        j = 1;
        while(j <= valor){
            printf("*");
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```